# Different logo on specific page / node

Tags: theming, 7

I have a special page called www.mydomain.com/special (whcih is a page node type). Only on that specific page, I want an extra image in the header of that page (next to the logo)

The logo and sublogo's is contained in the page.tpl.php provided by the previous themer.

What I would like to add in the page.tpl.php is somthing like:

```
if I am on page xyz
  <div>extra logo</div>
endif
```

It this possible or am I totally wrong?

Comment: yes it is possible, are you using Drupal 6 or 7 ? check the naming convention for specific page here https://drupal.org/node/1089656

Comment: Are you adding an additional logo or swapping out the logo for one page?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the node `NID` of this special page, it would be a quick...

```
<?php if ($_GET['q']=='node/NID'): ?>
  <div>extra logo</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

...in your `page.tpl.php` file.  You could also create a special template for this node:

```
page--NID.tpl.php // for Drupal 7
page-NID.tpl.php  // for Drupal 6
```

...and have it in there all the time.

If you want to make sure that `www.example.com/special` uses a special template regardless of what `node/NID` it is really, eg, `special` is really an alias for `node/6` or something, then you will need to get a bit more "special" with some preprocessing to look at the path alias and check if it is `special` and then do things different.  And I say preprocessing because there should be as little logic in the templates as possible.

Answer (score 0):

current_path() function should be available in page.tpl.php. Just check the result and add what you need.

Or, like pointed out in the comment, duplicate page.tpl.php and name it page--special.tpl.php, clear your cache, and add what you need.
Keep in mind that this new .tpl will apply only to your /special page, so you wont need to check the url.

Answer (score 0):

If could, in template.php of your theme, declare preprocess_page hook and add a variable:

```
<?php

function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {      
  // Change this "if" with your logic
  if (current_path() == 'mypage') {
    $vars['custom_text'] = 'custom text';
  }

}
?>
```

Next, in your page.tpl.php, add the variable near the title, like this:

```
<h2><?php print $title ?>
  <?php if ($custom_text) { print $custom_text; } ?>
</h2>
```